# Split text file to rows and columns based on delimeters

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a text file with data contents as below:

```
<SUB    A=a; B=b; C=c; D=d <END <SUB    A=e; B=f; C=g; D=h <END <SUB    A=i; B=j; C=k; D=l <END...
```

I wish to use power bi to have the below table.

[Expected table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5Fyp.png)

```
A   B   C   D
a   b   c   d
e   f   g   h
i   j   k   l
…   …   …   …
```

I have tried splitting the data based on the semi column and the equal to sign as delimeters, but I do not have the required results.

When I load the text file, I have two columns which is not what is required:

```
<SUB    
        A=a
        B=b
        C=c
        D=d
<END    
<SUB    
        A=e
        B=f
        C=g
        D=h
<END
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not clear what you are looking for. Can you please explain what result you are looking for?

Comment: Hello Aldert, I have a .txt file with data " <SUB A=a; B=b; C=c; D=d <END <SUB A=e; B=f; C=g; D=h <END <SUB A=i; B=j; C=k; D=l <END..." and I want to use power bi to covert this data to the a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like the code below. I directly assign the text (copy-pasted from your question) to an expression, but I presume you are loading the text file via `File.Contents` in conjunction with `Text.FromBinary` or `Lines.FromBinary` (or something similar).

**Approach 1**

```
let
    textFromFile = "<SUB    A=a; B=b; C=c; D=d <END <SUB    A=e; B=f; C=g; D=h <END <SUB    A=i; B=j; C=k; D=l <END", // copy-pasted from your question
    betweenEachSubAndEnd = 
        let
            startIndexes = List.Transform(Text.PositionOf(textFromFile, "<SUB", Occurrence.All), each _ + Text.Length("<SUB")),
            endIndexes = Text.PositionOf(textFromFile, "<END", Occurrence.All),
            tableOfIndexes = Table.FromColumns({startIndexes, endIndexes}, type table [start = Int64.Type, end = Int64.Type]),
            extractText = Table.AddColumn(tableOfIndexes, "extracted", each Text.Range(textFromFile, [start], [end] - [start]), type text)
        in extractText,
    SplitAndCleanIntoRecords = (textToParse as text) as record =>
        let
            splitOnVerticalDelimiter = Text.Split(textToParse, ";"),
            whitespaceTrimmed = List.Transform(splitOnVerticalDelimiter, Text.Trim),
            keyValuePairs = List.Transform(whitespaceTrimmed, each Text.Split(_, "=")),
            accumulatedRecords = List.Accumulate(keyValuePairs, [], (recordState, currentPair) => Record.AddField(recordState, currentPair{0}, currentPair{1}))
        in accumulatedRecords,
    recordColumn = Table.AddColumn(betweenEachSubAndEnd, "toExpand", each SplitAndCleanIntoRecords([extracted]), type record),
    expanded =
        let
            headersToExpand = List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(recordColumn[toExpand], Record.FieldNames))),
            removeOtherColumns = Table.SelectColumns(recordColumn, {"toExpand"}),
            expandColumn = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(removeOtherColumns, "toExpand", headersToExpand)
        in expandColumn          
in
    expanded
```

I start off with some text like this:

[image: Input text]

and end up with a table like this:

[image: Output table]

**Approach 2**

```
let
    textFromFile = "<SUB    A=a; B=b; C=c; D=d <END <SUB    A=e; B=f; C=g; D=h <END <SUB    A=i; B=j; C=k; D=l <END A=m; B=n; B=o; C= null<END",
    replaceSubAndEnd = List.Accumulate({"<SUB", "<END"}, textFromFile, (textState as text, currentValueToReplace as text) as text => Text.Replace(textState, currentValueToReplace, ";")),
    SplitAndTrimEach = (textToSplit as text, delimiter as text) as list =>
        let
            split = Text.Split(textToSplit, delimiter),
            trimmed = List.Transform(split, Text.Trim)
        in trimmed,
    splitOnVerticalDelimiter = SplitAndTrimEach(replaceSubAndEnd, ";"),
    dropEmpty = List.Select(splitOnVerticalDelimiter, each _ <> ""),
    keyValuePairs = List.Transform(dropEmpty, each SplitAndTrimEach(_, "=")),
    toTable = Table.FromRows(keyValuePairs, {"header", "value"}),
    grouped = Table.Group(toTable, {"header"}, {{"columns", each _[value], type list}}),
    transformedTable = Table.FromColumns(grouped[columns], grouped[header])     
in
    transformedTable
```

(To implement, open the query editor, click `Advanced editor`, copy-paste the code above. You will need to adjust the code for loading the text file.)

Comment: Thanks. Based on my example, it works perferctly. I have one more question. If the data is tweaked to something like this "<SUB A=a; B=b; C=c; D=d <END <SUB A=e; B=f; C=g; D=h <END <SUB A=i; B=j; C=k; D=l <END A=m; B=n; B=o; C= null<END", how can I have the same table. Column A is always unique.

Comment: @Longora, see if second approach works better or not.

Comment: Thanks, Can I have the forth row with output as such:                                            "m   n,o null null"?